# To interact with SharePoint projects in Visual Studio, your system user account must have administrator privileges

Tags: windows, sharepoint, privileges

When deploying a SharePoint visual web part project, I encountered some privilege issues.

1. If I run VS2012 with a domain account which has full control to SharePoint site. The following error message occurred:
   To interact with SharePoint projects in Visual Studio, your system user account must have administrator privileges
2. Then I try to run VS2012 with Administrator, another error message occurred.
   Error   Error occurred in deployment step 'Retract Solution': A timeout has occurred while invoking commands in SharePoint host process.
3. I try to add the original domain account to local Administrator group and WWS_ADMIN_WPG, and try to run VS2012 with it, the same message in 1 occurred.

**I want to give my domain account all Administration privileges which are needed to interactive with SP project. But it seems that local Administrator group and WWS_ADMIN_WPG still don't have enough permission to do this.**

How can I solve these issues? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to run Visual Studio as administrator (Right click -> "Run as administrator")?

Comment: Hi @Greg, first, I create the project, added a visual web part and deployed it. These above are all done using VS2012 running as administrator. Then, I add a second visual web part and try to deploy it using administrator and it said it must be SP farm admin to re-deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running VS as admin, by right clicking on Visual studio icon, then clicking "Run as administrator"

Comment: Getting pretty fed up with Microsoft these days.  Why in the world do I need to run something as administrator when I AM an administrator?  Where do they come up with this stuff?

Comment: The problem is when I try to run the visual studio as Administrator my sharepoint connection does not go through